# String with unicode character inside can't be displayed properly

Tags: android, string, unicode, character

I'm doing and android app and I've to display a String in a TextView. For some reason the String I recieve are like a mixture of normal and unicode characters.

For example, I recieve the String "**Caf\u00e9**" and in textview should appear "**Café**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use this

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

and use [this method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The library worked perfectly for my purpouse but instead of using unescapeHtml(String s) I had to use unescapeJava(String s) as the first one returned the String as it was.